# java.lang.NullPointerException:sessionfactory is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I am using spring with hibernate and getting null as sessionFactory when I try to save my data.I try hard but not able to find why I am getting sessionFactory as null;

Below are my XML and java classes

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/River] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at river.amit.com.dao.LoginDao.savePerson(LoginDao.java:19)
        at river.amit.com.service.LoginService.saveLogin(LoginService.java:18)
        at river.amit.com.LoginController.handleRequest(LoginController.java:28)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)







 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  
        <bean id="viewResolver"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
           <property name="mappings">
            <props>
               <prop key="/hello.html">helloController</prop>
               <prop key="/login.html">loginController</prop>
             </props>
           </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="helloController" class="river.amit.com.HelloWorldController"/>
        <bean id="loginController" class="river.amit.com.LoginController"/>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="hl" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="localeResolver"       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" />
            <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
          <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
            <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/river"></property>  
            <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
            <property name="password" value=""></property>  
        </bean>  
            <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
             <property name="mappingResources">  
            <list>  
            <value>\river\amit\com\curd\login.hbm.xml</value>  
            </list>  
            </property>  
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <value>
                    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </value>
            </property>
         <!--    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
                <props>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
                   </props>  
            </property>  --> 
        </bean>  
           <!-- <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
        </bean> -->  
                  <!--      <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean> 
          -->
         <bean id="logindao" class="river.amit.com.dao.LoginDao">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
        </bean>   
        </beans>

public class LoginDao {
    //private HibernateTemplate template;
    public void LoginDao(){};
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   /* public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }*/
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    public void savePerson(Login login){  
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(login);
    }  
}



public class LoginService {
    private LoginDao logindao;

    public LoginDao getLogindao() {
        return logindao;
    }

    public void setLogindao(LoginDao logindao) {
        this.logindao = logindao;
    }

    public void saveLogin(Login login) {
        getLogindao().savePerson(login);
    }
}


package river.amit.com;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

import river.amit.com.curd.Login;
import river.amit.com.dao.LoginDao;
import river.amit.com.service.LoginService;

public class LoginController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String name = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        Login login = new Login();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (name != null) {
            login.setName(name);
            login.setPassword(password);
            LoginService service = new LoginService();
            service.setLogindao(new LoginDao());
            service.saveLogin(login);
            String message = "HELLO " + name;
            return new ModelAndView("test", "message", message);
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("errorpage", "message",
                    "Sorry, username or password error");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the code you getting this error?

Comment: You have not correctly injected a sessionFactory to your LoginDao class. With the information provided, that is all we can tell you. I suggest adding Spring and Hibernate Config and the relevant code from `LoginDao`

Answer (score 0):

You need Spring to manage your beans for you.

You can't do this:

```
LoginService service = new LoginService();
service.setLogindao(new LoginDao());
```

As those beans are now not going to be managed by Spring and so the sessionFactory is not injected.

You need to get Spring to create a `LoginService` and Autowire it in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Autowire` annotation instead of creating instance of `LoginService` on your own.

```
@Autowire
LoginService service;
...
...
@Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    service.saveLogin(login);
```